# Authorization approaches and design patterns for Node.js applications

Tags: security, node.js, design-patterns, express, authorization

I am building a multiple page admin interface for an internal enterprise software platform. Think lots of glue logic tying together various APIs, db queries, and shell scripts.

We will be using node.js, the express framework (including jade templates), and LDAP for authentication.

I am struggling to find information regarding design patterns and best practices for authorization in node applications. Preferably, I would like to use the role-based model since my users are familiar with that approach and its care and feeding.

I am new to node.js so please don't assume I've already seen a module or popular blog post. It's probable that there's a wealth of information and I simply do not know where to look.

Thanks in advance for any information you are able to provide!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As per your first question, you want some authorization process implementation in NodeJs. I have explored and used number of APIs of NodeJs. I would prefer following APIs for enterprise applications.

- For Authentication: [Passport](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport) or [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) if developing SPA (front-end) in AngularJS.
- For Authorization: [ACL](https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl) . Role based security on Methods and REST APIs. I would like to mention [casbin](https://github.com/casbin/node-casbin) if you want to use RABC, ABAC as well.

Second, you want some implementation and development approach in NodeJs.

- Easy and my favourite design pattern and Framework for NodeJs: MVC framework , [SailsJs](http://sailsjs.org) . For its ready to start and modular architecture. Code management is easy in long run (Most practical requirement for an enterprise application). Easy maintenance. SailsJs is also preconfigured with [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), using which you can create real time modules, widgets, chat widgets with in your project.
- [Express](https://expressjs.com/) You can use Express and design your own custom MVC project structure. This is also popular and robust. You can find popular seed projects of the same on [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)
- [Redis](https://redis.io/) As a caching or session layer. It is always good to use seperate caching or session layer, because it won't block you to scale your application on cloud to nth instances.
- You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/) and [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) to create real-time features like [Geo-location](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd) , user-presence(online/offline), chat, push-notification and many more.
- ORM: [Waterline](https://www.npmjs.org/package/waterline) . For its easy querying approach. It is also the inbuilt and default ORM of SailsJs. You can also use [Sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), if not using SailsJs. I would recommend to use native connectors provided by DB providers.
- Database: As per your requirement. Waterline ORM supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB and more..
- My faviourite view engine: [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/). No need to learn new things for developing your presentation layer. It is also the inbuilt and default view engine of SailsJs, that's why I am a fan of SailsJs.

I think, I have covered all important information to create an Enterprise application in NodeJs. I don't say, above packages are best, but collaboratively, they can be best fitted to any enterprise scenario. There are other known packages, which you can use according to your own requirement.

Comment: waterline and sails.js +1

Comment: @kosnkov Most of these are fine. Check out [HapiJS](http://hapijs.com) for a more powerful alternative to Express, and [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) for an alternative to Waterline. In my opinion, I think SailsJS is overkill. If you come from a RAILS or Django background, you should understand enough concept to be fine with just Express/Hapi and Waterline/Sequelize; it's much more light weight vs Sails. I opt for Hapi / Sequelize.

Comment: Nice list. It'd be also good to add a tiny note about brute-force protection. Package like [rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) should be a good fit.

Answer (score 17):

Here are some information to get started:

- [passport](http://passportjs.org/) is a popular module for authentication
- [express auth example](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js) shows how do implement simple authentication without extra modules
- [express route middleware example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-middleware/index.js) explains how to implement role based authentication
- [blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/09/08/ldapjs-a-reprise-of-ldap/) on nodejs.org about the [ldapjs module](http://ldapjs.org/)

Hope that makes it easier to start.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out those links. The express route middleware example seems very close to the use-case I have

Comment: Strange that your answer does not contain the word Authorization :)

Comment: Perfect answer, helped me a lot.  Even without the word authorization :)

Comment: Broken link https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js

Comment: @Green - https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js

Comment: @iamrudra Thank you. I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [CASL](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/) which is very good integrated with MongoDB. Also there is an article of how to itegrate authorization based on CASL into expressjs app - https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/authorization-with-casl-in-express-app-d94eb2e2b73b

Answer (score 1):

I should say [Node-Authorization](https://github.com/VinceZK/authorization) is also a good candidate. The idea is borrowed from SAP(ERP provider), it is an object oriented authorization. And it can also be used as an accompaniment with other frameworks like: Passport and Express.