# How to configure authentication interceptor on Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have Node.js microservices run behind Nginx server
I've created a new Node.js service to authenticate and authorize access to all other services
I want nginx to allow access to the requested services based on authentication service response

**for instance:**
If user request "/user/id/edit"
I want Nginx to direct the request first to "/auth"
then base on "/auth" response Nginx decide to continue with "/user/id/edit"
or return an error as a response

I can't find any tutorial or documentation about this case

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code taken from [Spotify-Web-Auth-API-Example](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/authorization_code/app.js):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});
```

As you can see from above code, within your node.js code itself, you could perform redirection (redirection of request to login endpoint) to authorization service and then control the access.

You do not need a nginx configuration explicitly.

Moreover, please read this related query - [Authorization approaches and design patterns for Node.js applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546249/authorization-approaches-and-design-patterns-for-node-js-applications)

Comment: I know how to do it from Node itself  But, Actually, I want to add authentication as a separate layer

Comment: I can Achieve the wanted result when working with AWS API Gateway  .. They provide a method to add your authenticator as interceptor for all APIs that you have .. I want something similar with Nginx.